# Find with mtime doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I have made a folder in home and I have touched a file inside. Now I am executing

```
find /home -mtime 1
```

but it doesn't find anything. Is that normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
find /home -mtime -1
```

As per `man find`:

```
-mtime n[smhdw]
    If no units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference between 
    the file last modification time and the time find was started, rounded up to the next 
    full 24-hour period, is n 24-hour periods.

    If units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference between the 
    file last modification time and the time find was started is exactly n units.
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add `+` or `-` to the integer value depending on your need. The system can not understand that `1` is by default `+1`

Comment: `1` indicates modified time exactly equal to 1 day whereas `+1` indicates modified time greater than 1 day. 1 day in linux is as per 24 hours duration from the current time and not as per difference in the dates.